# Customer Portal: StandardSetController for Cases with filterId set to "My ..."-type of list views

Tags: apex, customer-portal, list-view, standardsetcontroller

I'm confused by the behavior of my `StandardSetController` for cases when its `filterId` is set to "My ..." type of list of views (e.g., "My Cases", or list views where Filter By is My Cases).

As a comparison:

**CP user using standard list view page for cases:**

`User selects list view "My Closed Cases", returns 5 records.`

***Additional question**: The above 5 records are actually **owned** by a queue. The CP user is just a contact in these cases. Is this normal CP behavior, or am I overlooking a sharing permission?*

---

**CP user using custom list view VF page with StandardSetController**

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController controller = 
    new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
    'select id, subject from Case'));

controller.setFilterId('00B70000006XQz5EAG'); // List view id of "My Closed Cases"

system.assertEquals(5, controller.getResultSize()); // 5 == 0, False!
```

***Additional detail**: Further testing shows that the controller only returns records where the user is actually the owner.*

I'm not sure which of the two scenarios is behaving properly.

Comment: are the queue cases visible in your vf page at all? I.E. if you just query [select id from case where id in :mycaseids] for those 5 cases are 5 rows returned?

Comment: Is the user a member of the queue  in addition to being the contact ?

Comment: @GregGrinberg Yes, they are visible. I think perhaps SF refers to Case.ContactId on "My" list views for CP users.

Comment: @techtrekker The user is not a member of the queue.

Comment: @jmrjulian I think you might be on to something with that. Easy way to test would be to create a case as a portal user and then change the owner and see if it still shows up in the listview.

Comment: @GregGrinberg Done this. Seems like the controller doesn't follow this special ownership rule.